# Maps API keys for geocoding never working

Tags: android, api, google-maps

I have enabled Google Maps Geocoding API and Google places API for Android to obtain POI from a query to google maps. I have also the Server key. 
My link is this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=lat,lng&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=food|bar|store|museum|art_gallery&key=my_server_key
```

I obtain this result:

```
{
    "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure that this API is activated in the APIs Console: Learn more: https://code.google.com/apis/console",
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "results" : [],
           "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

if I delete the key part of the link I obtain this:

```
{
    "error_message" : "This service requires an API key.",
           "html_attributions" : [],
           "results" : [],
           "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

how can I fix this?? 
thx

Comment: generate new key and try that

Comment: @USKMobility what key??

Comment: serverkey or you can also try with browserkey

Comment: no changes. I tried to change both keys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enable only following services Google Maps Geocoding API and Google places API for Android  . Places API for android is used with android framwork, it can not serve restful webservice. To get response from your url enable **"Google places API web service"**